# jQuery / JSON object in each loop

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

Im currently trying to populate empty fields created when a selection is made. (selecting images from a media modal).
When the media modal is closed, new empty fields are created and the selections are saved. 
In order to get the different data (different image sizes) i had to go with json eventhough im very new to json, thats the only way i can get the data.

Now i am trying to populate the empty fields with the data i have from the selection, but all fields gets populated only by the last URL..

```
// When files is selected
        mediaUploader.on('select', function() {

            //Get the selection from the modal..
            selection = mediaUploader.state().get('selection');

            //Get the amount of selections made in the Media Modal...
            selection_count = selection.length;

            //Simulate "Add new images" the selection amount of times..
            for(var i = 0; i < selection_count; i++) {
                jQuery(theMetabox).find('.js-wpt-repadd').trigger('click');

            }

            //Map it...
            selection.map( function( attachment ) {

                //JSONIFY THE ATTACHMENTS
                attachment = attachment.toJSON();

                //Get the thumbnail size URL from JSON
                var thumbnailUrl = attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url;
                //Get the full size URL from JSON
                var fullUrl = attachment.url;


                //LOG IT IN CONSOLE FOR TESTING (Works perfect..)
                console.log(thumbnailUrl);//Outputs all thumbnail URLS in console
                console.log(fullUrl);//Outputs all full URLS in console


                jQuery('.wpt-form-textfield[value=""]').each( function(index) {

                    //Mark the new fields with red border (testing.. working...)
                    jQuery(this).css('border','2px solid red');
                    jQuery(this).val(fullUrl[index]); // <--- This is the issue, this returns the index number of the fullUrl instead of the url that it shows in the console..

                });

            });

            //Reset selection..
            selection = null;


        }); //END ON SELECT IMAGES
```

Comment: Suggest you create a [mcve] demo in a javascript sandbox site like jsfiddle.net. Not sure why you need an `each` loop inside `map` which is itself a looping method

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) i have now minimized the code.
Im not sure i have completely understood the .map function then.
I could move the each function outside the map since the population takes place after, but then i cant use my variable "fullPath", it says its undefined then..